# faceloop selection does not work

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

[image]I want to select a faceloop by using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>, but if do that, Blender selects all the faces of my mesh. What could be wrong? Are there other ways to select faceloops?

Comment: What does your mesh look like? Can you include screenshots?

Comment: Here's the screenshot.

Comment: Is it possible that this mesh actually _is_ one continuous faceloop?

Comment: Aha, I've checked this out and you are right. So now my next challenge is to make the torus with seperate loops. Thank you both for answering.

Comment: Was the poke and convert to quads used when creating that torus ? I didn't see [anything unusual](http://i.imgur.com/hkP6DwV.jpg) and couldn't really get how could be there one faceloop.